# IIS 6.0 recycle overlapping delay

Tags: iis, iis-6, recycle

Is it possible to add delay in overlapping iis 6.0 recycling? for example iis does not shutdown the old pool for 2 hours even the new app pool is live and processing requests. I`ve got sometimes a long running request.

I thought that 'shutdown time limit' property is right one for that but it`s not. IIS is still shutdown the old pool after about a minute and i recieve an error: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can specify an overlap.

You can configure that recycling will only happen at a specific time, for example 2 a.m when no users are using the system.

If you have a process that lives in memory for 2 hours, you should probably write info to disk, such that the process can start where it left off, in case the services fails.

Comment: Overlapping recycling is build-in feature http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0e570911-b88e-46be-96eb-a82f737dde5a.mspx?mfr=true

But it`s working very strange

Comment: I cannont find anything about overlapping in your link.

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Here is the right one http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3ee19598-ec90-4570-a4a5-d93a24400b99.mspx

Comment: You have probably done this, but just in case. Have you tried restarting the server, the configuration changes may require a machine restart.

Answer (score 0):

this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759201(WS.10).aspx
clearly states:
*In both types of recycling, the WWW service allows a configured amount of time for the old worker process to handle the requests that it has already taken from HTTP.sys before it shuts itself down.*

Comment: Yes i know that. This property should do that http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6d39d5a7-a043-4a6c-b854-b5c56d23531d.mspx?mfr=true

But it does not work after about a one minute iis shutdown the process

Comment: So you are saying that you modified ShutdownTimeLimit metabase property (set it to something long) but IIS still terminates the app pool after 1 minute???

Comment: You also need to increase Shutdown time limit to allow app pool to stay up for longer

Comment: Yes, I try through IIS console in app pool properties and through metabase the result is nothing.